# Leave rows in pandas dataframe based on a column in anotherr data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df

```
nhl_df=pd.read_csv("assets/nhl.csv")
cities=pd.read_html("assets/wikipedia_data.html")[1]
cities=cities.iloc[:-1,[0,3,5,6,7,8]]
cities = cities.rename(columns={'Population (2016 est.)[8]': 'Population'})
cities = cities[['Metropolitan area','Population']]
print(cities)


 Metropolitan area Population
0            New York City   20153634
1              Los Angeles   13310447
2   San Francisco Bay Area    6657982
3                  Chicago    9512999
4        Dallas–Fort Worth    7233323
5         Washington, D.C.    6131977
6             Philadelphia    6070500
7                   Boston    4794447
8   Minneapolis–Saint Paul    3551036
9                   Denver    2853077
10   Miami–Fort Lauderdale    6066387
11                 Phoenix    4661537
12                 Detroit    4297617
13                 Toronto    5928040
14                 Houston    6772470
15                 Atlanta    5789700
16          Tampa Bay Area    3032171
17              Pittsburgh    2342299
18               Cleveland    2055612
19                 Seattle    3798902
20              Cincinnati    2165139
21             Kansas City    2104509
22               St. Louis    2807002
23               Baltimore    2798886
24               Charlotte    2474314
25            Indianapolis    2004230
26               Nashville    1865298
27               Milwaukee    1572482
28             New Orleans    1268883
29                 Buffalo    1132804
30                Montreal    4098927
31               Vancouver    2463431
32                 Orlando    2441257
33                Portland    2424955
34                Columbus    2041520
35                 Calgary    1392609
36                  Ottawa    1323783
37                Edmonton    1321426
38          Salt Lake City    1186187
39                Winnipeg     778489
40               San Diego    3317749
41             San Antonio    2429609
42              Sacramento    2296418
43               Las Vegas    2155664
44            Jacksonville    1478212
45           Oklahoma City    1373211
46                 Memphis    1342842
47                 Raleigh    1302946
48               Green Bay     318236
49                Hamilton     747545
50                  Regina     236481
```

It has 50 rows.

My second df has 28 rows

```
       W/L Ratio
city                        
Arizona             0.707317
Boston              2.500000
Buffalo             0.555556
Calgary             1.057143
Carolina            1.028571
Chicago             0.846154
Colorado            1.433333
Columbus            1.500000
Dallas–Fort Worth   1.312500
Detroit             0.769231
Edmonton            0.900000
Florida             1.466667
Los Angeles         1.655862
Minnesota           1.730769
Montreal            0.725000
Nashville           2.944444
New York City       1.111661
Ottawa              0.651163
Philadelphia        1.615385
Pittsburgh          1.620690
San Jose            1.666667
St. Louis           1.375000
Tampa Bay           2.347826
Toronto             1.884615
Vancouver           0.775000
Vegas               2.125000
Washington          1.884615
Winnipeg            2.600000
```

I need to remove from the first dataframe the rows where the metropolitan area is not in the city column of the 2nd data frame.

I tried this:

```
cond = nhl_df['city'].isin(cities['Metropolitan Area'])
```

But I got this error which makes no sense

```
KeyError: 'city'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need select column `Metropolitan Area` and in second `cities` `DataFrame` index, last filter with `~` for invert mask:

```
cond = cities['Metropolitan Area'].isin(nhl_df.index)

df = cities[~cond]
```

If first clumn is not index in `city` `DataFrame`:

```
cond = cities['Metropolitan Area'].isin(nhl_df['city'])

df = cities[~cond]
```

Comment: I have this: KeyError: 'Metropolitan Area', If I put first city, the I get key error on city. which is very weird.

Comment: @LuisValencia - oops, just see it, I think you need swap `DataFrame`s names, answer was edited.